# Calling the old method call inside AsynTask doInBackground

Tags: android

I'm very new to android programming and I coded my app in Android 2.2. But when I tried to run my app in Android 3 or higher I get an error like :

```
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

In my android 2.2 I have a method like this:

```
public JSONObject makeServiceCall(String url, Map<String, String> params)
```

which is performing the network call operations. Looking into google I found I need to move this code to `AsyncTask` class of `doInBackground`.

But I have a trouble in changing the params of `doInBackground` as it takes `Object...` varags, where my method takes two parameter `String,Map<String,String>`.

Are there any work around I can do inside `doInBackground` to call my original `makeServiceCall`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use constructor of you custom `AsyncTask` to send multiple variable, then you don't need to send variable in `execute()` method. something like this:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

    private String mString = null;
    Map<String, String> mMap;
    public MyAsyncTask(String s, Map<String, String> map) {
        //assign values to class fields
        this.mMap= map;
        this.mString = s;

    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //access class fields here.
        }
}
```

use it as below in your any other Activity or other class:

```
new MyAsyncTask(yourString, yourMap).execute();
```

Comment: Thanks. My method returns the `JSONObject`. But if I follow this, this returns `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>`

Comment: You can change it according to your requirements, Replace the `Boolean` to `JSONObjec`t from Class declaration, return type of the `doInBackground()` and the `onPostExecuteMethod()` receiving parameter to `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Constructor`.

```
    new Download(str1,str2).execute();


 public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {      
   ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public Download(String st1,String str2) {

        String STR1 = str1;
                    String STR2 = str2;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog
                .show(context, "", "Please wait...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Call ur method use str1,str2
        return 0;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

}
```